# How to install a module in play 2 framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

How do I install a module in play 2.  In all of the github documentation that I see you add a line to your Build.scala appdependacies then you add a resolver in my main variable.  Then what?  Does the module install?  How do I know if it installed correctly?  I can't find any documentation on the Play website on this subject.

For an example of what I am talking about these are some modules that I am trying to install

Deadbolt 2
https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-guide/blob/master/02-introduction.markdown

Secure Social
http://securesocial.ws/guide/installation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `play update`, then you should see how Play resolves the dependencies. When the plugin is active, it should be displayed in the console upon app launch.

And yes, this could be improved in Play.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there anywhere in the documentation that can give more details on that?

Comment: Not really, however since this is only an extension to sbt, the best is to learn about sbt itself. I can recommend [sbt in action](http://www.manning.com/suereth2/).

Answer (score 0):

you have to add module details in **application.conf** file.
Example :

```
play {
  modules {
    enabled += "be.objectify.deadbolt.java.DeadboltModule"
  }
}
```